# Geolocation from multiple timestamps

Tags: geometry, statistics

I'm trying to geolocate where in the world a particular piece of data was sent from (via the Internet). I have multiple computers located in various cities around the world, and they all receive the data at different timestamps. I can potentially take thousands of measurements throughout the day.

If I make the huge assumption that latency is proportional to the great circle distance between two points, is there a way to combined my timestamp measurements to come up with a statistical best guess for where a particular piece of data is sent from?

For what it's worth, I'm trying to figure out location at the granularity of what country the data is coming from, not down to a residential area or something like that.

Comment: With that assumption, probably yes. Each measurement determines a circle on the sphere. In principle all those thousands of circles will intersect at a single point. But the assumption is probably far from even a good approximation. Latency depends on routing and routing hardware more than on distance. In fact you could test your assumption by looking at the pattern of intersections of the circles. Nonetheless, I think your problem is solvable even without the assumption. With that much data you can probably simultaneously find the source and understand the latencies. But it's not simple math.

Comment: "it's not simple math"

That's why I'm posting here :-)

Comment: By "not simple math" I meant that I think it's not mostly math at all - more like a statistics problem with a lot of noisy data. You could start by looking at a dozen measurements for one instance - draw the circles I suggest on a globe and look at the intersections.

Comment: Upvoted since it's an interesting question even though I think it's unanswerable without much more data. Note: seismologists locate earthquakes this way all the time (in 3d) - many stations recording time stamped tremors. But they have physical models for transmission rates.